# Converting a list of strings into a dictionary where the first 4 letters of each string is the key and the rest is the value in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list that looks like this :

```
my_list = ['some: abcde' , 'no some: zytej', 'some: dkfja', 'no some: sdfas']
```

I want to convert this into a dictionary where the keys would be either 'some' or 'no some' depending on how the string starts and the values to be the rest of the string like 'abcde' etc.

Is there a way I could do this?

I would really appreciate the help.

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. If you have identical keys, they'll just overwrite.

Comment: You cannot convert it properly into a dict, because dict has unique keys

Comment: Could I have done it the other way around? Like the the first part of the string as values and the latter part to be the keys?

Answer (score 0):

It can not be converted, since you will have collisions, because any key ('some', 'no some') can have a single value.

You can instead use 'some' / 'no some' as dictionary values and 'abcde' etc as the keys.

Comment: How could do that? Use 'some' and 'no some' as values and 'abcde' as the keys?

Comment: Oh I figured it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1.Create new dict

2.For every component in list split this component with **str.split()** by **":"**

3.Add new value to dict with our Key ( KeyVal is list like ["some","abcde"]).

But your keys should be different, either values in dict will be overwritten.

```
my_dict = {}
my_list = ['some: abcde' , 'no some: zytej', 'some: dkfja', 'no some: sdfas']
for component in my_list:
   KeyVal = component.split(':')
   my_dict[KeyVal[0]] = KeyVal[1]
```